# Render Controller Action To String (Using Virtual Path, No action/controller name) ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ok, im developing a MVC CMS like website and when declaring routes i used following pattern. I encapsulate action name and controller name into a class like so

```
public class UrlUtilsUnhandledErrorsExtensions
{
    private readonly UrlHelper _urlHelper;

    public UrlUtilsUnhandledErrorsExtensions(UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        _urlHelper = urlHelper;
    }

    public String GetLatestErrors()
    {
        return _urlHelper.Action("GetLatestErrors", "UnhandledErrors");
    }
}
```

Then instead of writing

```
@Url.Action("GetLatestErrors", "UnhandledErrors")
```

I write

```
@Url.Action(Url.Utils().UnhandledErrors().GetLatestErrors())
```

I find this approach much more easier to maintain, because if controller name changes i only have to change one class.

This works fine with any links, controller redirects (return Redirect(...)) and just anything that accept virtual path which is returned by

```
public String GetLatestErrors()
{
    return _urlHelper.Action("GetLatestErrors", "UnhandledErrors");
}
```

**But here comes the problem**: i cant use Html.Action() with this approach. It requires controller name and action name, but instead i want it to use virtual path.
After digging around and studying MVC source code i realized that i will need to write my own Html.Action extension method that will just accept virtual path.

**So here is my solution**

```
    public void ActionFromUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String url)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary rvd = null;

        rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();

        String action = String.Empty;
        String controller = String.Empty;

        foreach (Route route in htmlHelper.RouteCollection)
        {
            if (route.Url == url.Substring(1)) // url starts with / for some reason
            {
                action = route.Defaults["action"] as String;
                controller = route.Defaults["controller"] as String;

                break;
            }
        }

        RequestContext rc = ((MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;

        rc.RouteData.Values["action"] = action;

        rc.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;

        IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
        IController controllerImpl = factory.CreateController(rc, controller);
        controllerImpl.Execute(rc);
    }
```

It works, but since its based on Html.RenderAction method it just writes directly to output, so in my view when i write following code

```
@{ Html.ActionFromUrl(Url.Utils().UnhandledErrors().GetLatestErrors()); }
```

It renders my partial first, all above everything and then rest of html follows.
This is not the result i want, so i have to find out the way of rendering the result to string as Html.Action do. I already looked into the source code with dotPeek but coudn't figure out how to mix it altogether.

My question is: **Am i doing something wrong ? Or how can i write Html.Action overload so it accepts virtual path and returns MvcHtmlString ?**

Comment: Just to avoid mass replace on Controller name change, I user a static class containing string constants. And in ActionLink i use just ClassName.ConstantName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CMS, you probably do not need the whole convention-based view rendering, you will (sooner or later) want render custom templates "to string" and merge result layout by your (most probably dynamic/configurable) rules. Take a look on **RazorEngine** project.

http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, i totally agree with you. But this is my first CMS and frankly i don't have much experience writing such things. I'm not ASP.NET MVC expert either.
Thanks for the hint though, ill take a look at it and will happily use it if it suits my needs.

Comment: Ok, i think i started to understand the concept. Basically if you have page with some predefined areas you can use some sort of engine to "fill" this areas with arbitrary content ? Right now im using custom tags like <content id="123"></content> and HTML Agility Pack to parse HTML, get ids, fetch content from DB and substitute my pseudo tags. I think it could be performance issue later on, i even wanted to store the results in some NoSQL DB for better performance. Its still in the air though.

Comment: best advice i can give you : dont write your own CMS on technology you are new on. At least take some time to study some existing asp.net mvc CMS systems, and "borrow" what you like.. dont write it from scratch, it is VERY nontrivial work even for experienced programmer to design it right way

Comment: I've studied Orchard and NOP Commerce :) Orchard is non trivial, while NOP Commerce sources pushed me into right direction. Honestly its too late to say no and i like building stuff, so why not to try by trial and error. I'll get experience anyway.